# vs emulator of Cordova tool for visual studio 2015 RC

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I use visual studio 2015 RC to create a new cordova blank project and tried run it for **vs emulator** , but no any response , always get as follow message

**

> Validating emulator arguments... Determining if emulator is already
>
> running... Preparing virtual machine...

**

But if run in chrome or android emulator  , It's fine .

I check tool/visual studio Emulator for Android and tried launch , but it's fail and get some log information .

> [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
>
> [Informational] Launching Device: 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet
>
> [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
>
> [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
>
> [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
>
> [Informational] Launching emulator...
>
> [Critical] Could not launch 'VS Emulator 7" KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet'
> device.

What's i missing?

OS : Windows 10 (build 10074) EN

Tool : Visual Studio 2015 RC EN

Hyper-v : ON

Hardware : RAM 4GB

Comment: See if you can find the VS Emulator 7-inch KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet listed in hyper-v manager, try delete it and then I think it's better to restart your PC. Rerun you application again from VS to see if it makes any difference. Did you encounter problems when debugging using other emulators with "VS Emulator" prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't have enough ram.  The minimum for Visual Studio Emulator for Android is 8GB.

I have a laptop with 4GB of ram and it will not run.  I get an error in my build output:
 `"Could not reserve enough space for object heap."`

Notes: 
I tried editing the environmental variable with no luck
`Variable Name : _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable Value : -Xms256m -Xmx512m`

Windows Phone Emulator requires 4GB of Ram: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626524.aspx

Comment: feel so sad , in tool/visual studio Emulator for Android list , the emulator description just need 2GB ~ 4GB , why minimum must be 8GB , i am so confused and i am surprised the Android emulator can working fine ,but VS Emulator for Android can't

Comment: Here's a work around: Use Visual Studio Emulator for Android to run APK. It's not ideal, but it does allow you to view the project. **Instructions:** Run Visual Studio Emulator for Android (Tools > Visual Studio Emulator for Android). Close VS to free up memory. Drag and drop your APK to the device. You can find your APK in `bin > Android > Debug`.

Comment: Use3775437, do you have the link for the minimum system requirements? Maybe I'm missing something.  Also, does your build output (View > Output) include any errors?  I'm having the same problem on my laptop and would really like a solution.

Comment: User3775437, here's someone with the same exact problem. check out this link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/04/29/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-vs2015-rc.aspx  Scroll down to comments. It's definitely a RAM issue.

Comment: Hi DeanB_Develop , i don't have any document about  minimum system requirements , and actually i can't found any document about it .

Comment: I tried looking for minimum system requirements for Visual Studio Emulator for Android, but couldn't find any. Would be nice to get the actual specs.  Note: A 4GB RAM laptop for VS is pretty low.  I'm upgrading my RAM, but would be nice to have this running on low spec machines.

Comment: "We're still working on official documentation of the system requirements, but they are mostly the same as the Windows Phone Emulator (docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626524.aspx#windows)"

This makes me think you only need 4GB technically. Yes, 4GB is low.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/04/29/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-vs2015-rc.aspx